# How can I access button click from main in python, tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to python and tkinter GUI, I need to access button click action from the main function, is there any possibility to do that?  any way I can access it in click function inside the class that I have comment it. what is the correct method to do it? thank you

```
from tkinter import *


class Youtube:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        master.title('Youtube_Downloder')
        self.screen = Entry(master, state='normal', width=25, background="White", foreground="blue",
                            font=('Arial', 12))
        self.screen.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.layout = Label(master, text='Past the Link below', font=('Arial', 16),foreground="red")
        self.layout.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.create_button('Add Link',1,30)

    def create_button(self,val,row,column,width=12):
        button = Button(self.master, text=val, width=width, command=lambda: self.click(val))
        return button.grid(row=row,column=column)

    def click(self,clicked_button=None):
        if clicked_button == 'Add Link':
            #self.create_label(self.screen.get(), 3, 1)  #this methord working
            return 'Add Link'

    def create_label(self,text,row,column,font=('Arial',8)):
        return Label(self.master, text=text, font=font).grid(row=row, column=column)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    my_gui = Youtube(root)
    if my_gui.click() == 'Add Link':
        my_gui.create_label(my_gui.screen.get(), 3, 1)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven_programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Read through [`[tkinter] event driven programming`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+event+driven+programming+entry). ***`if my_gui.click() ==`***, this is invalid, what do you want to accomplish here?

Comment: @stovfl , I did n't know about event driving , I  wanted know can access that I ask way since " In an event-driven application, there is generally a main loop that listens for events, and then triggers a callback function when one of those events is detected"

Comment: @PythonAmateur742, try with self it can access button , that action cannot get , thank

Comment: ***How can I access button click from main***: You can't do anything in `def main():` because this part of your code is only executed **once** at startup. Please, respond to my question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming it could be this button:

```
def create_button(self,val,row,column,width=12):
        button = Button(self.master, text=val, width=width, command=lambda: self.click(val))
        return button.grid(row=row,column=column)
```

Change `button` to `self.button`. When you've done that you can access it in main by using `my_gui.button`.

If you ever decide to use an mvc model, this will be the approach as well.